# Query to select appropriate feedback record based on dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I understand there are many questions and answers outlining how to query data with relation to dates stored in SQL. My question, while in the same vein, is not something I've been able to find a solution for.

There is a SolutionRevisions table with three relevant columns: SR_ID (primary), SR_SolutionID, and SR_CreatedDate.

There is a Feedback table with F_ID, F_ItemID (maps to SR_SolutionID) and F_CreatedDate, F_SubItemID (currently empty).

**My goal is to identify which SolutionRevisions record was the active when a feedback item was created and insert the SR_ID value into F_SubItemID column.** This could be done by choosing the revision record created most recently **before** the feedback item.

To begin, I've began by trying to select back appropriate values for testing and verification. What I have looks like this:

```
SELECT sr.SR_ID, f.F_ItemID, sr.SR_CreatedDateUtc, f.F_CreatedDateUtc 
FROM Feedback AS f
INNER JOIN SolutionRevisions AS sr on f.F_ItemID = sr.SR_SolutionID
WHERE f.F_CreatedDateUtc > sr.SR_CreatedDateUtc
```

This is obviously missing a necessary portion of the where clause (thus returning inaccurate results). The where clause needs to include (in pseudo-code)

```
AND f.F_CreatedDateUtc < nextSRCreatedDate
```

^ where "nextSRCreatedDate" represents the sr.SR_CreatedDate of the next record on the SolutionRevisions table for the same SR_SolutionID. **My issue lies in getting back the correct value for nextSRCreatedDate**

Example data:
[image]

Any help is appreciated, if more info is requested I'll promptly reply.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Will get some and share momentarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach instead. It uses a subselect to determine the most recent record in the SolutionRevisions table at the time any individual Feedback record was created.

It's probably not the fastest solution (pun intended), but it should get you the desired results. If you're able to alter the subselect to a hit a better index, that would of course help with the execution time.

```
Update
    f
Set
    f.F_SubItemID = (
        Select Top 1
            sr.SR_ID
        From
            SolutionRevisions sr
        Where
            sr.SR_SolutionID = f.F_ItemID
            And sr.SR_CreatedDateUtc < f.F_CreatedDateUtc
        Order By
            sr.SR_CreatedDateUtc Desc
    )   
From 
    Feedback f
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this out and if it works mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to identify which SolutionRevisions record was the active when a feedback item was created and insert the SR_SolutionID value into F_SubItemID column.

I think you want `outer apply`:

```
SELECT sr.SR_ID, f.F_ItemID, sr.SR_CreatedDateUtc, f.F_CreatedDateUtc 
FROM Feedback f OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT sr.*
      FROM SolutionRevisions sr 
      WHERE f.F_ItemID = sr.SR_SolutionID AND
            f.F_CreatedDateUtc >= sr.SR_CreatedDateUtc
      ORDER BY SR_CreatedDateUtc DESC
     ) sr;
```

Comment: thank you for the response. Is your answer how I get the nextSRCreatedDate I was trying to get for the where clause or do you think that SQL statement is all I need? When I scope your query to a single SolutionID I get the same number of results that I get from my query when scoped to the same SolutionID. (This should be 17, as there are 17 feedback items, but both return 523 items)
Some clarity with respects to how I'm to implement your answer would be great.

Comment: @JakeofSpades . . . This answers your question.  I'm not sure what your comment is referring to.

Comment: I'll check the results and if so mark it as answered, thank you.